# Direct limits and inverse limits commuting

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

Recently in a reading I was doing, I ran into a fact I do not seem to be able to prove.

The claim was that finite direct limits commute with inverse limits.

It was also claimed that inverse limits commute (without finiteness).

Under what conditions is this true? Is it true in any category with direct and inverse limits, or is some set like structure required for proof? Additionally, I would like to read a proof of the above mentioned statements if you would be willing either to answer with one or tell me where I could find one.

Thank you much for any help or direction.

Comment: It's a disjoint union modulo an equivalence relation for the direct limit, and a subset of the product for inverse limits. Isomorphisms between them are easy, just establish one on the pieces which are consistent with the transition functions. If it helps:  think about direct limits as unions and inverse limits as intersections, and see how the proof goes for those two first.

Comment: The claim is wrong. In $\mathsf{Set}$ and hence in every algebraic category (over $\mathsf{Set}$), *finite limits* commute with *filtered colimits*. Apart from that almost nothing can be said in general about commutation between limits and colimits.